# Azure Storage Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I recently upgraded a couple of my projects. Now for some reason I am using the same code and getting an error about the object reference when I try to create a new container. I uninstalled all the packages and reinstalled them. I made sure System.Configuration was referenced. I am not sure what else to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;

                    try
                    {
                        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(AnyFolder);
                        container.CreateIfNotExists();
                        container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex);
                    }
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ErieRewards.Rewards.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +7391
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177

Comment: Well it doesn't mean much... all the stack trace is just that?

Comment: Yes that is all of the stack trace on the page

Comment: Which line of code is failing?  Try adding diagnostics trace statements to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I added try catch to the code and the error is the same                            System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ErieRewards.Rewards.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) On which line in your code you're getting this NullReferenceException and 2) Which version of Storage Client library are you using (and what version was before that)?

Comment: I figured out the issue. This was the line that was giving me the error CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

Comment: I changed the line to this and it works fine.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);

Comment: I was using version Azure Storage 4.3 now I am using version 5.0. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely putting your connection string into your app settings and not your connection strings within your web.config file.

I would suggest trying the following line of code to load your connection string instead, or moving your connection string to the connection string section of your web.config

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionStr‌​ing"]);
```